# url Redirection and rewrite using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

i am try to rewrite the dynamic url in to SEO url.i was create htaccess code for that But the problem is when a user will Type the address like **http://example.com/anoop**  ,  **http://example.com/anoop/vvv** or **http://example.com/anoop/vvv/kkk** then it will goes to error page.At last i was decide to automatically add backslash in every directory. i was created htaccess code for that

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/(.*[^/]+)$ /$1/ [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?cat=$1&sub=$2 [L]
```

But the now automatically add backslash in to **http://example.com/anoop/** .but i want to add backslash if not present backslash

eg

```
http://example.com/anoop/activity -     http://example.com/anoop/activity/
http://example.com/anoop/act/page -     http://example.com/anoop/act/page/
```

now the **http://example.com/anoop/activity** will be redirected to error page.Please help me any one to rewrite the program

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem. You want to add a backslash? It looks like it worked! How are you trying rewrite the URL? If you rewrite the URL for a web application the web application will have to process the URL and display data accordingly. Are you rewriting the URL for a web application or for a static website?

**EDIT**

Here is how Wordpress does it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: web application content fetch from database

Comment: You would just catch the URL and send it to the web application for processing. See my edit for an example on how Wordpress does it.

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d using ,which is the  get from  this url **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871614/ll.html**